# How to automatically resubmit the form in Firefox on error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In case a (say login) form POST submission fails and Firefox displays "**Try Again**" message.

Is there any way to click this "Try Again" automatically or through any settings in Firefox about:config that it clicks it?

[Related](http://webadventurous.com/mozilla-firefox-auto-resend-confirmation/)

Comment: How is this related to Firefox WebExtension development?

Answer (score 1):

"Clicking" the *Try Again* button is relatively easy.  There is [an extension that does just that](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/make-a-merry-try-again/), and lets you set the number of seconds between retries.

The real rub here is that you want to "blindly" retry form `POST`s.  As we all know, just because you didn't get a response, that doesn't necessarily imply that nothing was changed on the server.

Re-submitting a login form sounds harmless enough, and usually is.  But if you imagine forms that result in orders being placed or money being moved, it's easy to understand why browsers have implemented this kind of warning:

[image: Form re-submission warning]

This is what you'll see if you enable an extension like TryAgain and a form post fails.  It's the same behavior you'd get by pressing F5 yourself.  The extension will dutifully try to `POST` again, but the browser is going to intervene with an alert, and refuse to send the `POST` until "Resend" is clicked.

This kind of safety feature does a fair amount to protect end-users and developers from poor implementations and network hiccups.  However, it's really going to work against what you're trying to accomplish.

That said, if you *could* figure out a way to modify the extension to detect the alert and somehow click "Resend", you'd be in business.  I can't say for sure that this is impossible, put it kind of looks that way, at least for now: [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1351938) was marked as "won't fix", and [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323098) is still open.

Comment: Thanks I'm half way done. For the rest half way I'd need to change and build the source of Firefox

Comment: @user5858 If you are done, could you please help me out I am needing the similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension for firefox:
[auto reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-auto-reload/)

but i would warn you. because you could auto send any sensitive data. usually web browsers ask  reload because the dont want any sensitive data to be submitted without user discretion.

Comment: No I want POST form resubmission